# How to implement MWFeedParser in my project

Tags: ios, rss

I'm trying to use the MWFeedParser library in my app. On my homescreen, I have a view controller named NewsViewController. 
In the MWFeedParser library, the root view controller is called RootViewController. I've tried to copy all the code from the RootViewController into the NewsViewController .H + .M and in IB I've linked the tableview to "dataSource" and "delegate". But when my app starts the tableview is empty.
Here's how to code looks like:

.H:

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import "MWFeedItem.h"
    #import "MWFeedParser.h"

    @interface NewsViewController : UITableViewController  <MWFeedParserDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {

        // Parsing
        MWFeedParser *feedParser;
        NSMutableArray *parsedItems;

        // Displaying
        NSArray *itemsToDisplay;
        NSDateFormatter *formatter;
        IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
    }

    // Properties
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *itemsToDisplay;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
    -(IBAction)goHome;

    @end
```

.M:

```
#import "NSString+HTML.h"
#import "MWFeedParser.h"
#import "DetailTableViewController.h"

@implementation NewsViewController

@synthesize itemsToDisplay, tableView;


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark View lifecycle

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"News", @"News");
        self.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_news"];    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    label.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0f, 1.0f);
    label.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0xB3/249.0 green:0xB3/252.0 blue:0xB3/253.0 alpha:1];
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    // Date
    // Setup
    formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
    [formatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
    parsedItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    self.itemsToDisplay = [NSArray array];

    // Refresh button
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh
                                                                                            target:self
                                                                                            action:@selector(refresh)];
    // Parse
    NSURL *feedURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mywebsite.com/feed/"];
    feedParser = [[MWFeedParser alloc] initWithFeedURL:feedURL];
    feedParser.delegate = self;
    feedParser.feedParseType = ParseTypeFull; // Parse feed info and all items
    feedParser.connectionType = ConnectionTypeAsynchronously;
    [feedParser parse];

    UIImage *someImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"back_active1@2x.png"];
    [button setBackgroundImage:someImage forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    static BOOL first = YES;
    if (first) {
        UIViewController *popup = [[Home1ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Home1ViewController" bundle:nil];

        [self presentViewController:popup animated:NO completion:nil];
        first = NO;
    }
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Parsing

// Reset and reparse
- (void)refresh {
    self.title = @"Refreshing...";
    [parsedItems removeAllObjects];
    [feedParser stopParsing];
    [feedParser parse];
    self.tableView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    self.tableView.alpha = 0.3;
}

- (void)updateTableWithParsedItems {
    self.itemsToDisplay = [parsedItems sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:
                           [NSArray arrayWithObject:[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"date"
                                                                                 ascending:NO]]];
    self.tableView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    self.tableView.alpha = 1;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark MWFeedParserDelegate

- (void)feedParserDidStart:(MWFeedParser *)parser {
    NSLog(@"Started Parsing: %@", parser.url);
}

- (void)feedParser:(MWFeedParser *)parser didParseFeedInfo:(MWFeedInfo *)info {
    NSLog(@"Parsed Feed Info: “%@”", info.title);
    self.title = info.title;
}

- (void)feedParser:(MWFeedParser *)parser didParseFeedItem:(MWFeedItem *)item {
    NSLog(@"Parsed Feed Item: “%@”", item.title);
    if (item) [parsedItems addObject:item];
}

- (void)feedParserDidFinish:(MWFeedParser *)parser {
    NSLog(@"Finished Parsing%@", (parser.stopped ? @" (Stopped)" : @""));
    [self updateTableWithParsedItems];
}

- (void)feedParser:(MWFeedParser *)parser didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Finished Parsing With Error: %@", error);
    if (parsedItems.count == 0) {
        self.title = @"Failed"; // Show failed message in title
    } else {
        // Failed but some items parsed, so show and inform of error
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Parsing Incomplete"
                                                         message:@"There was an error during the parsing of this feed. Not all of the feed items could parsed."
                                                        delegate:nil
                                               cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss"
                                               otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
    [self updateTableWithParsedItems];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table view data source

// Customize the number of sections in the table view.
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

// Customize the number of rows in the table view.
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return itemsToDisplay.count;
}

// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }

    // Configure the cell.
    MWFeedItem *item = [itemsToDisplay objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if (item) {

        // Process
        NSString *itemTitle = item.title ? [item.title stringByConvertingHTMLToPlainText] : @"[No Title]";
        NSString *itemSummary = item.summary ? [item.summary stringByConvertingHTMLToPlainText] : @"[No Summary]";

        // Set
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15];
        cell.textLabel.text = itemTitle;
        NSMutableString *subtitle = [NSMutableString string];
        if (item.date) [subtitle appendFormat:@"%@: ", [formatter stringFromDate:item.date]];
        [subtitle appendString:itemSummary];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = subtitle;

    }
    return cell;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // Show detail
    DetailTableViewController *detail = [[DetailTableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    detail.item = (MWFeedItem *)[itemsToDisplay objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detail animated:YES];

    // Deselect
    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

}

@end
```

Please help me fix this!

Comment: Did you start troubleshooting by placing breakpoints anywhere?

Comment: How do you mean? I just started program, which means I'm not so familiar with this... Sorry. @mattyohe

Comment: Breakpoints allow you to stop execution during runtime so that you can inspect the state of the application. Here's apple's docs one this: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-source_editor/Creating,Disabling,andDeletingBreakpoints/Creating,Disabling,andDeletingBreakpoints.html

Answer (score 0):

you can follow the following link to use MWFeedParser : https://0club1.blogspot.in/

If your Table view is empty, you could have got the following error:

NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed

To allow HTTP, we need to allow arbitrary loads in App Transport Security Settings. Select info.plist in your project, in Information property list add new list as App Transport Security Settings.
Within that add Allow Arbitary Loads and mark it as YES.

[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]